# Foreign Key in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-cli

I have three tables(models): Users,preferences,ideas. Users has a column 'username' as a primary key and I would like to add 'username' as foreign key to the other tables . How is it done in sequelize? I am a noob at sequelize ,so please do answer this. The hasMany,belongsTo were confusing to me. It would be really helpful if someone answers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two objects: **User** and **Preference**, you can specify the relationship as follows:

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Preference = sequelize.define('Preference', {
    id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    //Below, 'users' refer to the table name and 'username' is the primary key in the 'users' table
    user: {
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       references: {
          model: 'users', 
          key: 'username', 
       }
    }
});

User.hasMany(Preference); // Add one to many relationship
```

I would suggest to read the following document to understand better:

[Sequelize Foreign Key](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#foreign-keys)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks . So the same thing is done for other table also right?

Comment: Yes...same like Preference